# Array of days in between months

Tags: javascript

I have two dates: Startdate and enddate
startdate = "10/10/2018" enddate = "03/09/2019"

I am trying to create an array of dates between those 2 dates. I have the following code.

```
function getDateArray (start, end) {
            var arr = [];
            var startDate = new Date(start);
            var endDate = new Date(end);
            endDate.setMonth( endDate.getMonth());
            while (startDate <= endDate) {
                arr.push(new Date(startDate));
                startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + 1);
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

Then calculate the number of days between those months in between.
10/10/2018 to 11/10/2018 = 30 days
11/10/2019 to 12/10/2018 = 30 days or so depending on number of days between the 2 dates and then create an array of the dates.

[30,30,31....till end date]

```
        function daysBetween(date1, date2 )
        {
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
            var dayDifference = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
            return dayDifference;
        }
```

I tried the following code and it's returning the array of number of dates however, it's not accurate. It keeps returning 32 days in October. The output it's giving right now is as follows. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here but it looks like it's only going till February and displaying the result.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    Output: [32,30,31,31,28]

    var dateArr = getDateArray(z, y);
            console.log(dateArr);
            var dayCounts = "";
            for (var x = 0; x < dateArr.length-1; x++)
            {
                dayCounts += daysBetween(dateArr[x], dateArr[x+1]);
            }
            console.log("datearrlength" + dateArr.length);
            console.log(dayCounts);
```

Comment: What do you need as the end result, just a flat array with all the dates from start to end? Then I would simply use one loop, that increases the date by one day in each iteration (that can be done across month boundaries with JavaScripts Date object, advancing the day by one on 2018/01/31 will automatically land you in February), instead of that rather convoluted (and wrong, not _every_ day has 1000 * 3600 * 24 seconds, at least not in regions with DST) calculation in `daysBetween` …

Comment: I feel like an idiot, I posted an answer in C# not JS. Sorry, I deleted it.

Comment: Is there a reason not to base your work on a proven library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com)? It allows you to add/subtract, compute differences, tell how many `daysInMonth` for a given month... well, all the utilities you'd need.

Comment: @misorudeThere are 31 days from 10/10/2018 to 11/10/2018 but for some reason it's printing 32. Also, the array ends 1 month before the enddate.

Comment: @StockOverflaw Yes. Because when i started i didn't use the libraries and i am looking for a quick fix because i have a lot of date/time functions going on so one change would affect everything else.

Comment: IMHO, you could use a lib for the quick fix - i.e. keeping your functions' current I/O formats - and reuse that same lib for... the next quick fix you'll need! ;) In that case, the angle from the answers (going by small steps of 1 day) seems your safest bet, considering how twisted the calendar is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code worked for me. I added 1 extra month to my end date and it gives the proper date range. Also, instead of Math.ceil, i used Math.round and it gives the right number of date.

```
function getDateArray (start, end) {
        var arr = [];
        var startDate = new Date(start);
        var endDate = new Date(end);
        endDate.setMonth( endDate.getMonth());
        while (startDate <= endDate) {
            arr.push(new Date(startDate));
            startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + 1);
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work for you,

```
Date.prototype.addDay= function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

function getDateBwStartandEnd(sdate, edate) {
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var currentDate = sdate;
    while (currentDate <= edate) {
        dateArray.push(new Date (currentDate));
        currentDate = currentDate.addDay(1);
    }
    return dateArray;
}
```

** Shamelessly copied from web, but this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

While the following doesn't answer your question it is an alternative approach to the overall problem you are attempting to solve.

One approach would be to simply get the time difference between the two dates and then divide by the number of microseconds in a day. As you will notice though it is not exact and so a floor is used to get the days. There are other concerns with this approach as well such as date ranges before the epoch but it is a very simplistic approach and might work depending on your needs.

```js
const startDate = '10/10/2018';
const endDate = '03/09/2019';

const start = (new Date(startDate)).valueOf();
const end = (new Date(endDate)).valueOf();

const timeBetween = end - start;
console.log({timeBetween, days: Math.floor(timeBetween/86400000)});
```

A slightly more robust is to essentially use a counter that increments itself by adding 1 day to the counter and the start date while the start date is less than the end date. Again, there are some concerns with this approach but that also depends on your needs.

```js
const startDate = '10/10/2018';
const endDate = '03/09/2019';

let start = new Date(startDate);
const end = (new Date(endDate)).valueOf();

let daysBetween = 0;

while (start.valueOf() < end) {
  daysBetween++;
  start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(daysBetween);
```

Finally, a more robust solution to avoid the variety of issues with manipulating and working with dates is to use a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). Using its [`difference` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) would look like the following.

```js
const start = moment([2018, 10, 10]);
const end = moment([2019, 3, 9]);
console.log(end.diff(start, 'days'));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```